# Single page or multiple pages?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make a web service where users can make their own pages. Which is the better solution:

a. Execute everything on one page with get variables, using clean urls

or...

b. Make seperate .php files for every user

Is it a problem to have all the traffic of 500-1000 users on one page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second is not an option at all. It just makes no sense in the context of the *dynamic web pages*

Go for the first.
this is how every web site in the world works

Comment: Thanks. I just needed some encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to look up what `Your Common Sense` has said.

Imagine you DID applied the second options, then suddenly your website booms like facebook. What do you think you will do, create over millions of pages for each user.

That is one of the worst concept <sup><sup>*NO OFFENCE*</sup></sup>, create a common page for every user to land on, control the content and elements as per them.